# Cannot run cucumber and test in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I get an error when I try to run `cucumber` or `test` tasks in RubyMine. `spec` runs fine.

> Permission denied - db/test.sqlite3

This is the trace. How can I fix it?

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\bin\rake cucumber --trace
Testing started at 23:35 ...
WARNING: Cucumber-rails required outside of env.rb.  The rest of loading is being defered until env.rb is called.
  To avoid this warning, move 'gem cucumber-rails' under only group :test in your Gemfile
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon) to get coloured output on Windows
** Invoke cucumber (first_time)
** Invoke cucumber:ok (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
rake aborted!
Permission denied - db/test.sqlite3
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:460:in `delete'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:460:in `block (3 levels) in '
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:483:in `block (3 levels) in '
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:19:in `'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `'
Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the cucumber-rails gem inside ONLY the test group in your Gemfile and add `require: false`. It should look like this:

```
group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  …
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is that the `ENV=test` parameter in the task configuration should be changed to `ENV=development`. Apparently there is a bug in RubyMine. http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-5748

This isn't really an answer